# Invalid argument in insertBefore statement

Tags: javascript

In this code:

```
function comrespond(){
    function addresform(){
    var resid = this.getAttribute('id'),
    grandParent = this.parentNode.parentNode,
    newrespondform = '<div class="commentresponse"><span></span><span><p class="author">Leave a reply:</p><form id="commentform" action="http://split.snippetspace.com/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" onsubmit="addcomment(); return false;"><input id="author" aria-required="true" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Your name"/><input id="email" aria-required="true" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email address" /><textarea id="comment" aria-required="true" name="comment" rows="8"></textarea><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Post Comment" /><input id="comment_post_ID" name="comment_post_ID" type="hidden" value="'+resid+'" /></form></span></div>';
    grandParent.parentNode.insertBefore(newrespondform, grandParent.nextSibling);
    }
    var responsebtn = document.getElementsByClassName('comment-reply-link');
    for(var i = 0; i < responsebtn.length; i++){
                    bindEvt(responsebtn[i], "click", addresform);
                };
```

this line returns as "invalid argument" in IE10:

```
grandParent.parentNode.insertBefore(newrespondform, grandParent.nextSibling);
```

I cannot seem to figure this one out. It is supposed to insert a piece of code after the grandparent of a cetain div.  Any ideas guys? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

newrespondform is a string. insertBefore takes a DOM element. You should change it to:

```
newrespondform = document.createElement('div');
newrespondform.innerHTML = '<span></span><span><p class="author">Leave a reply:</p><form id="commentform" action="http://split.snippetspace.com/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" onsubmit="addcomment(); return false;"><input id="author" aria-required="true" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Your name"/><input id="email" aria-required="true" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email address" /><textarea id="comment" aria-required="true" name="comment" rows="8"></textarea><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Post Comment" /><input id="comment_post_ID" name="comment_post_ID" type="hidden" value="'+resid+'" /></form></span>';
```

Here is the documentation for insertBefore: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore